# How to create Spool file in Oracle 10g Express Edition

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle-apex

I have Oracle Database 10g Express Edition installed. I am able to create Spool file in SQL Plus but I want to know that how can I create it in Application Express which we use in browser.

I am newbie to Oracle. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Where are you trying to create the file?  If you are trying to create a file on the database server, you can use the `utl_file` package.  If you are trying to create a file on the client, you'd need a tool that runs on the client and has access to the client's file system like SQL*Plus.  APEX runs on the server and doesn't have access to the client file system.  You can create a report in APEX and create a link that allows you to download a CSV version of the report, however.

Comment: @JustinCave Thanks for clearing. I am creating it on client. Is there any way to create it in by running complete script in one go
?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what "running complete script in one go" means.  If you are talking about a "script", meaning a file with one or more SQL statements and SQL*Plus commands, it doesn't make sense to try to use APEX to run that.  You'd need an actual client tool-- SQL*Plus or SQL Developer or TOAD or something similar.  APEX allows you to build web-based applications.  You can build an APEX app that allows the user to download a file but then you're building a small application not a "script".